# How do I create a simple slider with fade effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a simple basic jquery slider with just fade effect. Here is my html & css. I would be much appreciate if you can solve the javascript code for me :) Thanks in advance !

```css
.wrapper {width: 1200px;margin: 70px auto;}
.text_slider {overflow: hidden;display: block;width: 700px;height: 100px;border: 2px solid #42474D;position: absolute;}
.basic_content_slider {position: absolute;overflow: hidden;}
.basic_content_slider p {padding: 20px 70px;display: inline-block;color: #252a30;}
#btn1 {display: block}
#btn2 {display: none;}
#btn3 {display: none;}
#btn4 {display: none;}
#btn5 {display: none;}
.next, .prev {width: 40px;height: 40px;position: absolute;top: 30px;opacity: 0.2;}
.next {background: url(images/next.png) no-repeat;right: 0;}
.prev {background: url(images/prev.png) no-repeat;left: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="text_slider">
  <div class="basic_content_slider">
   <p class="panel_switch" id="btn1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, aspernatur, impedit, facilis voluptate quam ab esse nam cumque non vel rem nesciunt fugiat corporis repellat similique! Obcaecati, adipisci quos dolore.</p>
   <p class="panel_switch" id="btn2">Impedit, facilis voluptate quam ab esse nam cumque non vel rem nesciunt fugiat corporis repellat similique! Obcaecati, adipisci quos dolore.</p>
   <p class="panel_switch" id="btn3">Psum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, placeat, impedit, blanditiis, reprehenderit laboriosam officia a dolore illo quaerat quam alias perspiciatis dignissimos dolores minima ullam libero nemo odio inventore!</p>
   <p class="panel_switch" id="btn4">quaerat quam alias perspiciatis dignissimos dolores minima ullam libero nemo odio inventore!</p>
   <p class="panel_switch" id="btn5">Henderit laboriosam officia a dolore illo quaerat quam alias perspiciatis dignissimos dolores minima ullam libero nemo odio inventore!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="next"></div>
  <div class="prev"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? on each slide to reveal next sentence? @Saji

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need the navigation bar as well. How do I do that ? Thanks

Comment: You should really first try to write the javascript yourself, and then if you have a specific question or issue we can address it. Instead you are asking people to just sit down and write code for you without first putting in your own share of the effort.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this several times but it doesn't work. I could have include javascript but don't know how to do this. Yes, you're right. I'll try this myself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your css:

```
.panel_switch { opacity: 0; transition: opacity 0.5s; }
.panel_switch_active { opacity: 1; }
```

Add the panel_switch_active class to the first slide

Add following javascript (and include jQuery):

```
$(function(){
    $(".prev").click(function(){
        $(".panel_switch_active").removeClass("panel_switch_active").prev().addClass("panel_switch_active");
    });
    $(".next").click(function(){
        $(".panel_switch_active").removeClass("panel_switch_active").next().addClass("panel_switch_active");
    });
});
```

This is pretty basic though. You might want to read up on javascript and jQuery or look for a suitable plugin.

Edit: I've created a jsfiddle with a fully working version: https://jsfiddle.net/1pp92v1u/

Comment: For some reason It's not working. Could you please check it out ?

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: A little more tweaking had to be done. Check my answer in a minute.

Comment: Thanks @keewnn it worked :) I really appreciate your help. I could have done using plugins but I want to learn as much as possible about javascript. You're right though I need to look for the basic javascript codes.

Comment: One more thing. In the end of the slide/panel how can I get back to a btn1. I want it to repeat every time when I click navigation bar. @keewnn

Comment: @Saji , if he solved your problem you should mark his answer as accepted using the green arrow, so that he received credit.